# Recognise which tab made the request

Tags: javascript, ajax

This question probably doesn't have an answer. But, I thought I'd give it a shot.
I wrote a great one-page application. When the application starts up, the open tab "registers" itself with the server, which stores is as an "active" tab.

If user A changes XYZ in the workspace, every tab opened on that workspace, by any user, receives a notification that XYZ was changed. That triggers a reload in the clients, which will magically be updated. At the moment, I am doing this by polling. However, when it all works I can use things like WS or Socket.io to make things even faster.

**PROBLEM: every tab receives the notification. Even the tab that instigated it in the first place!** (as a result, an already-updated screen gets updated)

I somehow need the server to know the tab ID of the tab making the request. Remember that a user might have 5 tabs open: if they change XYZ, all tabs should receive the notification, EXCEPT the one that actually triggered it!

At the moment, I am passing the workspace ID for every Ajax request ( a user might be logged in, and have access to several workspace at the same time).

- Solution 1: append both workspace ID *and* tab ID for every request
- Solution 2: only use the tab ID for every request. The app will work out the workspace ID from the tabID (which knows which workspace it belongs to)
- Solution 3: ????? (Something that I am missing?)

Any ideas?

Comment: I see no problem with solution 1 or solution 2. For solution 1 the ajax requests would be the thing that takes the most time, sending one additional value wouldn't make much difference. Solution 2 is also fine, you will just be interpreting the sent data on the server. Personally, I would go with solution 2. I would also ensure that you secure your ajax requests (probably an encrypted tab id and secret key) and compare it on the server side once the request is sent

Comment: The problem with Solution 2 is that an Ajax call made from an "expired" tab will fail as the tab is no longer active. This has "interesting" side effects (see: suspend your PC, open it again, submit that form... and no, won't work). At least with Solution 1 the call can indeed work (although the program will get the notification of the change...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having the server worry about which tabs to send change notifications to you could have the tab that initiated the changes ignore the notification.

Two ways to do this come to mind:

- After changing the content a tab will ingore all notifications for a brief period of time. (This will work fine unless changes on multiple tabs happen in a short amount of time.)
- Have the tab create a "change id" that it sends to the server with the changes to xyz. The broadcast change notification contains this id and the sending tab recognizes it as the one it sent and ignores it.

Comment: The second option works fine as long as the client starts a "broadcast request". However, the client might start a completely unrelated operation, and the *server* might want to trigger the message for all connected tabs, except the one that made the change in the first place. I guess I could have an operationId, bit I'd have to remember to have it for _each_ request.

Answer (score 0):

You could experiment with [HTML5 Visibility API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/) with a fallback to `window.onfocus` & `window.onblur` events and suppress updating the page if it's currently visible/active.

Comment: How would you go about retrieving the missed updates while the page was inactive? That could become really ugly when the client thinks the page is in another state than on the server...